# MySql AutoIncrement error

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've been working on a code. when we delete a specific data from a sql table the primary key which gets deleted will be used in the next record we enter.

Here is my code :

```
DB.connector().createStatement().executeUpdate("delete from stud where SID='"+PK+"'");
DB.connector().createStatement().executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE stud AUTO_INCREMENT='"+String.valueOf(PK)+"'");
```

I cant seem to find the error in this code.

> PK = 4 at this instance.

The error is :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''4'' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1755)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1679)
at com.cyrax.crms.Student.jButton2ActionPerformed(Student.java:363)
at com.cyrax.crms.Student.access$200(Student.java:27)
at com.cyrax.crms.Student$3.actionPerformed(Student.java:167)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Please help!

Thank You.

Comment: Why would you do this? Let's assume the last inserted record got the auto_increment value of 1000. Now you delete the record with id = 1. Do you really want to reset the current auto_increment value to 1? Do you think this will work? And it seems you've doubled your quotes. Have a look at the difference between your two lines and your handling of "PK".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As primary key is an integer then you should not qoute ''

so remove '' from the below

```
DB.connector().createStatement().executeUpdate("delete from stud where SID='"+PK+"'");
```

like this

```
DB.connector().createStatement().executeUpdate("delete from stud where SID="+PK);
```

Comment: @NevinduBatagoda just remove the single qoutes around pk as I showed.`DB.connector().createStatement().executeUpdate("delete from stud where SID="+PK);`

Comment: @NevinduBatagoda Remove the String.valueOf() call too (second line of your code).